# C# Harmony Transpiler null field exception for one of two nearly identical calls

Tags: c#, transpiler, harmony

Here's my code. Question is at the bottom:

```
namespace DifficultyModNS
{
    [HarmonyPatch(typeof(Boosterpack),nameof(Boosterpack.Clicked))]
    public class OneVillagerChecks
    {
        public static Int32 frequency = 5;
        public static Int32 startChecking = 10;

        static IEnumerable<CodeInstruction> Transpiler(IEnumerable<CodeInstruction> instructions)
        {
            foreach (var instruction in instructions)
            {
                if (instruction.opcode == OpCodes.Ldc_I4_5)
                {
                    DifficultyMod.Log("Transpiling const 5 to variable");
                    yield return new CodeInstruction(OpCodes.Ldfld, operand: AccessTools.Field(typeof(Int32), name: "DifficultyModNS.OneVillagerChecks::frequency"));
                }
                else if (instruction.opcode == OpCodes.Ldc_I4_S && Convert.ToInt32(instruction.operand) == 10)
                {
                    DifficultyMod.Log("Transpiling const 10 to variable");
                    yield return new CodeInstruction(OpCodes.Ldfld, operand: AccessTools.Field(typeof(Int32), name: "DifficultyModNS.OneVillagerChecks::startChecking"));
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return instruction;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first log message prints. Then just after the second log message there's an exception:

```
[17:18:44] [Log : difficulty_mod] Transpiling const 5 to variable
[17:18:44] [Log : difficulty_mod] Transpiling const 10 to variable
ArgumentNullException: Invalid argument for ldfld NULL
Parameter name: operand
  at HarmonyLib.Internal.Patching.ILManipulator.WriteTo (Mono.Cecil.Cil.MethodBody body, System.Reflection.MethodBase original) [0x001b4] in <4a2409e6eb214388b8d6ab81d407350d>:0 
  at HarmonyLib.Public.Patching.HarmonyManipulator.WriteTranspilers () [0x00084] in <4a2409e6eb214388b8d6ab81d407350d>:0 
  at HarmonyLib.Public.Patching.HarmonyManipulator.WriteImpl () [0x00031] in <4a2409e6eb214388b8d6ab81d407350d>:0 
Rethrow as HarmonyException: IL Compile Error (unknown location)
  at HarmonyLib.Public.Patching.HarmonyManipulator.WriteImpl () [0x00382] in <4a2409e6eb214388b8d6ab81d407350d>:0 
  at HarmonyLib.Public.Patching.HarmonyManipulator.Process (MonoMod.Cil.ILContext ilContext, System.Reflection.MethodBase originalMethod) [0x00042] in <4a2409e6eb214388b8d6ab81d407350d>:0 
  at HarmonyLib.Public.Patching.HarmonyManipulator.Manipulate (System.Reflection.MethodBase original, HarmonyLib.PatchInfo patchInfo, MonoMod.Cil.ILContext ctx) [0x00006] in <4a2409e6eb214388b8d6ab81d407350d>:0 
  at HarmonyLib.Public.Patching.HarmonyManipulator.Manipulate (System.Reflection.MethodBase original, MonoMod.Cil.ILContext ctx) [0x00007] in <4a2409e6eb214388b8d6ab81d407350d>:0 
  at HarmonyLib.Public.Patching.ManagedMethodPatcher.Manipulator (MonoMod.Cil.ILContext ctx) [0x00012] in <4a2409e6eb214388b8d6ab81d407350d>:0 
  at MonoMod.Cil.ILContext.Invoke (MonoMod.Cil.ILContext+Manipulator manip) [0x00087] in <92bbbc5a09fc417ca7426fbdd31824c2>:0 
  at MonoMod.RuntimeDetour.ILHook+Context.InvokeManipulator (Mono.Cecil.MethodDefinition def, MonoMod.Cil.ILContext+Manipulator cb) [0x00012] in <925d74c1e4e3467a888e7df55b8370c5>:0 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) MonoMod.RuntimeDetour.ILHook+Context.DMD<MonoMod.RuntimeDetour.ILHook+Context::Refresh>(MonoMod.RuntimeDetour.ILHook/Context)
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) MonoMod.Utils.DynamicMethodDefinition.Trampoline<MonoMod.RuntimeDetour.ILHook+Context::Refresh>?1194592624(object)
  at HarmonyLib.Internal.RuntimeFixes.StackTraceFixes.OnILChainRefresh (System.Object self) [0x00000] in <4a2409e6eb214388b8d6ab81d407350d>:0 
  at MonoMod.RuntimeDetour.ILHook.Apply () [0x00059] in <925d74c1e4e3467a888e7df55b8370c5>:0 
  at HarmonyLib.Public.Patching.ManagedMethodPatcher.DetourTo (System.Reflection.MethodBase replacement) [0x00047] in <4a2409e6eb214388b8d6ab81d407350d>:0 
// there's more but it's just additional subsystems rethrowing
```

Why does one of these work but the other one doesn't when the two fields are sitting next to each other in the same class:

```
yield return new CodeInstruction(OpCodes.Ldfld, operand: AccessTools.Field(typeof(Int32), name: "DifficultyModNS.OneVillagerChecks::frequency"));
yield return new CodeInstruction(OpCodes.Ldfld, operand: AccessTools.Field(typeof(Int32), name: "DifficultyModNS.OneVillagerChecks::startChecking"));
```

EDIT: I removed the else if for the one that "doesn't work" and I've discovered the exception still happens, after this function exits. So now I guess the question is Why does this return NULL for the operand to Ldfld when the name should exist?

EDIT2: I was using the wrong IL instruction. And the Harmony AccessTools lib is garbage for getting FieldInfo. That was replaced with `typeof(OneVillagerChecks).GetField("frequency")`.

Comment: 1.  Do less in a single line of code.   2. Provide us with some details on the `AccessTools.Field` method.  Did you write it?  Is it some library?  If it's a library function, give the name of the library and the complete name, including namespace, so we know what you're talking about.

Comment: It looks like you are passing completely wrong values for both arguments of `AccessTools.Field`. [The documentation](https://harmony.pardeike.net/api/HarmonyLib.AccessTools.html#HarmonyLib_AccessTools_Field_System_Type_System_String_) wants the declaring type, not the property type.

Comment: I was using the wrong IL instruction. AccessTools is part of Harmony.